# Jenkins hangs when running Xcode Unit Tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I am attempting to run my Xcode unit tests using Jenkins.  I can run them from Terminal on my build server using this command with out any issues:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme MyProject -destination OS=7.0,name="iPad"
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/dev/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyProject/build
```

However when I try to add that command to my build script (buildscript.sh) file, it hangs when running the unit tests.  I also tried adding a new Xcode task to Jenkins and running with these parameters:

XcodeSchema File:  MyProject

Configuration: Debug

Custom xcode build arguments: test -destination OS=7.0,name="iPad" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/dev/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyProject/build

It is hanging on a build file in the debug-iphone simulator folder.

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
.
.
.
/bin/sh -c /Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject
-ggdmamhydtxxzadkbjuusdjmholn/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug
-iphonesimulator/MyProjectApplicationTests.build
```

I took a look at the build file and the environment variable it is using is set correctly.

**MyProjectApplicationTest.build**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run the unit tests in this test bundle.
"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
# "${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests"
# "${PROJECT_DIR}/XcodeScripts/RunPlatformUnitTests
```

The RunUnitTests file exists in that directory.

I don't know if Jenkins is having issues running the simulator.  I spent most of the day yesterday racking my brain on this.  If anyone has any ideas on what the issue may be, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry I can't answer your question. But when I set up a jenkins CI system for iOS it took days and days and days of headache. If you can I'd suggest switching to XCode bots - instead of days to set up it took just an hour when I made the switch.

Comment: did you figure this out, I am having same problem

Comment: @Essenceofchicken what are "XCode bots"?

Comment: @stonedauwg Xcode's automated CI build system jobs. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem and found that jenkins user is not correctly set up to run test case on simulator. Follow instruction given on below website:

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/ios-ci-with-jenkins

see the section "SETTING UP THE JENKINS USER".

hope it will work for you as well.